# How can I edit the .bash_profile?

Tags: bash

I want to use matplotlib in Python, but it gives me this error:

> ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8

So I searched the internet and people suggest that I should edit my `.bash_profile`. But when I open it I can't edit since it is locked! So I searched about unlocking `.bash_profile`, this time people suggest using this command in terminal:

```
sudo chown My username ~/.bash_profile
```

But after entering my password, it says:

> chown: My username: illegal user name

Why does it say my user name is illegal? I have no idea what to do about. I would appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: How do you know the file is locked. The suggestions do not deal with a locked file

Comment: Is your user name the results of the command- `id -un`?

Comment: When I open the .bash_profile It doesn't let me to write anything in it and above the window it's written locked. Also when I want to unlock it says I don't have the permission. So I found that I should give myself permission through terminal but couldn't since it says illegal username(maybe the command is not right, but I don't know any other way to unlock it)

Comment: This Is what I see: amins-MacBook-Pro:~ aminsh$ sudo chown amins-MacBook-Pro ~/.bash_profile
Password:(I write my password here but it doesn't show anything however when I press enter I see the next line)
chown: amins-MacBook-Pro: illegal user name

Comment: First of all `~/.bash_profile` does not exist by default.  Secondly if it was created _normally_, by you, then you should already own it and it shouldn't be _locked_. What's the output of: `ls -leO@ ~/.bash_profile`  If the output has `uchg` in it then use this command to unlock it: `chflags nouchg ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @user3439894 This is my .bash_profile content: ""alias showFiles='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES; killall Finder /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app'
alias hideFiles='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO; killall Finder /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app'

# added by Anaconda3 4.0.0 installer
export PATH="//anaconda/bin:$PATH"
""

Comment: @user3439894 Also this is the answer I get when I do your suggestion: ""amins-MacBook-Pro:~ aminsh$ ls -leO@ ~/.bash_profile
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  - 328 May 23 10:17 /Users/aminsh/.bash_profile""

Comment: The reason you cannot edit it is because it's owned by `root` and you'll need to change ownership to you. You'll have to preface the `chown` command with `sudo`. , e.g.: `sudo chown $(id -u -n) ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks a lot dude, You solved my problem :)

Comment: @Amin Shn, Glad to have helped however you should mark jherran's answer as correct, as he did update it with info from the comments, and this will help others in the future to see an accepted answer as having the right information to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
chown $(id -u -n) ~/.bash_profile
```

Using the `chown` command in that way, you can be sure that is using your username (`id -u -n`).

Additionally, as @user3439894 says, if you get permission errors with previous command, your should add `sudo` before the command to execute the command as `root`:

```
sudo chown $(id -u -n) ~/.bash_profile
```

From `id` man page:

> id - print real and effective user and group IDs
>
> -n, --name: print a name instead of a number
>   -u, --user: print only the effective user ID

From `chown` man page (suggested by @fd0):

> For obvious security reasons, the ownership of a file may only be altered by a super-user.

Comment: This is what I see again :    amins-MacBook-Pro:~ aminsh$ chown $(id -u -n) .bash_profile
chown: .bash_profile: Operation not permitted
amins-MacBook-Pro:~ aminsh$ chown $(id -u -n) ~/.bash_profile
chown: /Users/aminsh/.bash_profile: Operation not permitted

Comment: You should add a note about using `sudo` with `chown` when the target is not presently owned by the `$USER` trying to change the ownership of the target filename.

Comment: You might add the following from the `chown` man page- `For obvious security reasons, the ownership of a file may only be altered by a super-user.`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing the bash_profile from the home directory? This honestly shouldn't be locked for any reason. The simple gui approach here would be to unlock via get info in finder (I'm assuming you're on a mac).

Comment: This issue was previously resolved. The file was owned by root instead of by the user who was trying to edit it.